# Нужно ли писать медиа-запросы для каждого элемента или существуют другие методы?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

Пишу тестовый проект для портфолио, сейчас занят адаптацией под мобильные устройства, и вот в процессе встал такой вопрос, неужели мне придется писать тонны кода для медиа-запросов, адаптируя каждую картинку и текст? Я не боюсь писать большое кол-во кода, я лишь боюсь что это не самая лучшая практика и я чего-то не знаю, поэтому хочу попросить совета у знающих людей.

Comment: не ясно..............

Comment: @АлексейШиманский попробую пояснить на примере вот такого элемента: https://codepen.io/dhelfy/pen/dyZEWQz ; Я сделал блок с лого и названием компании, неужели мне придется адаптировать каждый элемент этого блока вручную, как я сделал это в медиа-запросах?

Comment: Зависит от того, что конкретно вы хотите сделать. Например, [вот этот сайт](https://fuckingwebsite.ru/) не содержит ни одного медиа-запроса, но при этом идеально адаптирован абсолютно под все существующие устройства

Comment: @andreymal Слишком толсто)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar зато правда. А на [оригинальном сайте](http://motherfuckingwebsite.com/) так и вообще ни одного css-стиля нету :)

Comment: Но реально, всё зависит от самого сайта, не всегда требуется изменять вообще всё на мобильном экране, возможно те же гриды и флексы через wrap перестроят уже и так всё. Потом размеры текста глобально можно так же поменять в одном месте, а не в каждом месте по отдельности. Скорее всего не придётся писать слишком много медиа-запросов, но их в любом случае будет достаточно...

Comment: @andreymal Да, но смотря какое веб-приложение. Если это одностраничник с ссылками на ваши соцсети, то, конечно, тут ничего не надо будет, а иначе попробуйте то же самое сказать в адрес какого-нибудь фейсбука или ВК)))

Answer (score 0):

изначально в версте нужно предусмотреть некоторые моменты - это использование флексов, адаптивной сетки грид(если требуется) - в этих технология предусмотрены настройки для адаптива (тема глубокая - надо изучать), избегать фиксированной ширины у блоков и картинкам сразу прописывать адаптивные стили(ширина 100%, максимальная ширина, высота авто) и тогда значительно уменьшиться кол-во кода при адаптации сайта)

Answer (score 0):

> Нужно ли писать медиа-**запросы для каждого элемента** или существуют другие методы?

если имеешь ввиду под каждую картинку выделение отдельного медиа запроса, даже в том случае если для всех границы одни?
разумеется в этом нет необходимости. медиа запросы работают как контейнеры
вот наглядный рабочий пример:

```css
@media screen{
  #a{color: #500;}
  #b{color: #a00;}
  #c{color: #c00;}
  #d{color: #999;}
 }
@media print{
  #a{color: #005;}
  #b{color: #00a;}
  #c{color: #00c;}
  #d{color: #ccc;}
}
```

```html
<b id=a>a</b><br/>
<b id=b>b</b><br/>
<b id=c>c</b><br/>
<b id=d>d</b><br/>
```